# How can I get anti-diagonal views in armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I would like to access a matrix's [anti-diagonals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-diagonal_matrix) as views. Is this possible in armadillo?

People wanted to see my code

```
vec get_antidiag (const mat & A, const uint k) {
    const uint n = A.n_rows;
    const uint m = A.n_cols;
    const uint start_row = max(0, static_cast<int>(k+1-m));
    const uint end_row = min(k, n-1);
    const uint len = end_row - start_row +1;
    vec v (len);
    for (uint i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        v(i) = A(i+start_row, k-(i+start_row));
    }
    return v;
}

void set_antidiag (mat & A, const uint k, const vec v) {
    const uint n = A.n_rows;
    const uint m = A.n_cols;
    const uint start_row = max(0, static_cast<int>(k+1-m));
    const uint end_row = min(k, n-1);
    const uint len = end_row - start_row +1;
    for (uint i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        A(i+start_row, k-(i+start_row)) = v(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: what have your tried already? show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `diagvec()` and `fliplr()` to extract the diag

```
vec get_antidiag (const mat & A, const uint k) {
    mat B=A;
    B = fliplr(B);
    return diagvec(B,k);
}
```

Haven´t found anything for setting the diag ...

Comment: It would be more efficient to simply do `return diagvec( fliplr(A), k );`